Driver Scope Issue
I am trying to pick the product "ADIDAS ORIGINAL" from ecommerce site but my code is picking the product "ZARA COAT3".Dont know what is the reason?
My code is
package RahulShetty.SeleniumPractice;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 
public class AppTest {

@Test
public void practiceProject() throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client");
    
    String itema="ADIDAS ORIGINAL";

    driver.findElement(By.id("userEmail")).sendKeys("munna.srinath@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userPassword")).sendKeys("Srinath@230");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    
    
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"card-body\"]")));
    //all products
    List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"card-body\"]"));
    //Selecting adidas original webElement  
    WebElement element = items.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText().equals(itema))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
    //printing adidas original
    System.out.println("Selected item is :"+element.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText());
    
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    //But In scope of adidas original element picking up ZARA COAT3
    element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-body']/button[2]")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label=\"Product Added To Cart\"]")));
    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[routerlink=\"/dashboard/cart\"]")).click();
    }
    }

Iam here limiting the driver scope to select the product adidas original . But my code is picking the ZARA COAT 3
 //all products
 List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"card-body\"]"));
//only adidas original webElement
WebElement element = items.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText().equals(itema))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
//Here product is adidas original
System.out.println("Selected item is :"+element.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText());

Thread.sleep(4000);
//But picking here ZARA COAT 3
element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-body']/button[2]")).click();


element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-body']/button[2]")).click();

Above line seems to be the issue. The XPath in the above code is locating and clicking Add to cart button of "ZARA COAT 3" and not "ADIDAS ORIGINAL"
Solution: Use the below code instead:
String itema="ADIDAS ORIGINAL";

element.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='" + itema + "']//following::button[2]")).click();

Or hardcode ADIDAS ORIGINAL within XPath expression as below:
element.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='ADIDAS ORIGINAL']//following::button[2]")).click();

XPath expression explanation:
//b[text()='ADIDAS ORIGINAL']//following::button[2]


this XPath expression selects the second <button> element that appears after a <b> element with the text "ADIDAS ORIGINAL" in the HTML document


why it is clicking ZARA COAT 3. element scope is in ADIDAS ORIGINAL na and it is printing ADIDAS ORIGINAL  in the below line.                                                                                                                                 System.out.println("Selected item is :"+element.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText());           scope is in  ADIDAS ORIGINAL why it is going to ZARA COAT 3 scope.

This line element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-body']/button[2]")).click(); which is actually clicking the Add to cart button is locating ZARA COAT3 and not ADIDAS ORIGINAL

WebElement element = items.stream()
.filter(item -> item.findElement(By.tagName("b")).getText().equals(itema))
.findFirst().orElse(null); In this step I am locating to ADIDAS ORIGINAL right. Now this element belongs to ADIDAS ORIGINAL right. How it goes to ZARA COAT 3.

element.findElement(By.xpath("//b//following::button[2]")).click(); even this is pointing to zara coat 3. I have checked in the console, there are 5 b tags out of which zara coat 3 is the third index. why b of third index is getting selected.

For each product, there is a set of elements that corresponds to that element, e.g. the product image, product name, product price, View button, and Add To Cart button. The problem with your code is that you haven't specified the Add To Cart button that corresponds with the "ADIDAS ORIGINAL" product.
If I were writing this code, I would assume that I'm going to want to add different products to the cart in different tests so I would create a method to add a product to cart based on the product name. In that method, we need an XPath that finds the product name and then finds the corresponding Add To Cart button (or any of the other elements I listed above). Once you have that, you can easily call the method, pass in the desired product name, and it takes care of the rest.
This is how I would write that method
public static void AddProductToCart(String productName) {
    ExpectedCondition<WebElement> ec = ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(String.format("//div[@class='card'][.//b[text()='%s']]//button[text()=' Add To Cart']", productName)));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ec).click();
}

This is how I would write the test.
String url = "https://rahulshettyacademy.com/client";

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

String productName = "ADIDAS ORIGINAL";

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("userEmail"))).sendKeys("munna.srinath@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("userPassword")).sendKeys("Srinath@230");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

AddProductToCart(productName);


Some suggestions...

Always use a WebDriverWait and the ExpectedConditions clause that corresponds to the action. For example, if I'm going to click a button, use ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(). If I'm going to use .getText() or otherwise interact with an element, I need to wait until it's visible using ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated().
Don't use Thread.sleep(). It slows down your script, can cause intermittent issues, etc. Instead use WebDriverWait, see #1, above.
Whenever possible, use a single locator to find an element instead of grabbing one element, the searching from that element grab another, and again, etc. I know you're new and still learning but this will make your code much easier to follow, faster, and more efficient. It will also require you to learn how to handcraft CSS selectors and XPaths which will take some effort and time but in the end will make you a much better script writer.
Always prefer IDs and use By.id(). They are the least likely to change. Next prefer CSS selectors and use By.cssSelector(). They have a much simpler syntax, are easier to read, and are much faster than XPaths. Finally, only use XPaths when you must... 1) when you are locating an element by contained text or 2) when you have to do complicated DOM traversal (as I did in my AddProductToCart() method).

